# Get maintenance mode status

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to get maintenance mode status? I want to toggle the application from admin dashboard.

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('down');
dd($exitCode);
```

It always returns 0. I want to check if it's down then on next action turn the app up again.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, when you call `Artisan::call('down')` you will find there is a `down` file created in `storage/framework` you need to check if it exists or not

```
Storage::disk('framework')->exists('/down');
```

the disk

```
'framework' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('framework'),
],
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Your answer is good and he can found more info about that in this article, https://blog.devgenius.io/laravel-maintenance-mode-a2875028977d

Answer (score 3):

Via App facade.

```
app() -> isDownForMaintenance()
```